# Beyond Linux From Scratch: avrdude was compiled without usb support

Tags: linux, libusb, avrdude, linux-from-scratch

Out of interest and learning purposes I have built Linux from scratch (LFS+BLFS, both version 10.0) according to the descriptions on [www.linuxfromscratch.org](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org).

In general the OS can boot and I can basically work with it. There are a few things which are not smooth, therefore I would like to address the experts here.

I would like to get going the AVRDragon, a programmer for Atmel microcontrollers. To use it on Linux, I work with the program "avrdude". My goal is to learn how avrdude works and interacts with the OS. Therefore I would like to build it from source with debug information.

For building avrdude from source, libusb/libusb_1_0 and libelf are required. I understand that libusb_1_0 was installed with BLFS. avrdude asks for either libusb and/or libusb_1_0. I cannot say if there is a problem with having only libusb_1_0. (libusb_1_0 is newer than libusb, isn't it?) Additionally I have installed libelf (since libelf is installed, I cannot build the kernel anymore, but this should not be a problem for now). In the kernel, USB support is enabled (Device Drivers -> USB Support -> Support for Host-side USB).

I have created a udev rule:

```
# Dragon
ATTR{idVendor}=="03eb", ATTR{idProduct}=="2107", GROUP="plugdev", MODE="0666"
```

...and lsusb says this:

```
# lsusb
...
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 03eb:2107 Atmel Corp. AVR Dragon
...
```

Also, I use a script to program a sample application onto the microcontroller, which works on my reference system.

However, running avrdude on my BLFS, I get an error message, that avrdude was not built with USB support:

```
# avrdude -p m328p -c dragon_isp -B5 -F -P usb -V -U flash:w:Debug/hello_world.elf
avrdude was compiled without usb support.

avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

Researching the internet, indicated installing the prerequisites stated above and setting up the udev rule.

I have a good understanding of the Linux command line, the GCC tool chain and the usual Linux tools. But I am completely lost with how to correctly configure my BLFS with USB support. Is there somebody who can give me a hint on how to solve this problem? Many thanks!

Comment: Can you add the exact error message to the question? I'm having trouble googling the one provided.

Comment: Hi Nick, I added the exact error message to my description above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, for full functionality you need *both* libusb-1.0 and libusb-0.1. The `configure.ac` script defines `HAVE_LIBUSB_1_0` only for the former and `HAVE_LIBUSB` for the latter, while the `*.c` files containing your error message only check for `HAVE_LIBUSB`.

While current BLFS doesn't have instructions to build libusb-0.1, you can see them for libusb-0.1.12 [in BLFS 6.3](https://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/6.3/general/libusb.html).

Comment: While compiling libusb-0.1.12, [-Werror=format-truncation=] errors appeared. They could be prevented with: "make CLAGS=-Wno-format-truncation"

Comment: @ManfredHinter ah yeah, bad old *"`-Werror` in release"*... If you get more such `-Werror`-generated failures, you can prevent them with more general `CFLAGS=-Wno-error`.